# VSCode keeps giving me the same error: *"npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script."*

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

This is the error code i keep receiving in my terminal of VSCode:

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-26T07_31_43_854Z-debug.log
PS D:\scripts>
```

I dont know whats wrong, i reinstalled NPM, didnt solve the problem, i removed "test" from my package.json and replaced the "start":`node index.js` with "start":`node .`

Before this error, i received the error that package.json wasnt in the main folder, which i resolved by copying my discord-bot script, my package.json, the modules and the package.lock to my main folder. since then i kept getting this error

this is my discord-bot code right now.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new discord.Client();


client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("We have logged in for the first time!!");
});


client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content.startsWith("/av")) {

        var embed = new discord.MessageEmbed();

        embed.color = 0xf01000;
        embed.setImage(msg.author.displayAvatarURL());
        embed.description = "Coole avatar pik";
        
        msg.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
client.on("npge", (msg) => {

    if (msg.author.bot) {
        return
    }

    if (msg.content.startsWith("hello")) {
        msg.channel.send("hello!");

    }

})
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    console.log("member joined");
    member.roles.add(
        "803273046454566918"
    )
    

})

client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (fromID === me && text.includes("/repeat") ) {
        bot.sendMessage({ to: channel, message: txt.replace('/repeat ','') });
        
    }

})
    
client.login("TOKEN")
```

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.10
3 info using node@v14.15.4
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~prestart: discord-bot@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: discord-bot@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\scripts\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\James Kok\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\James Kok\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;;D:\Users\James Kok\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\James Kok\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\scripts
10 silly lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle discord-bot@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid discord-bot@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\scripts
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.4
19 verbose npm  v6.14.10
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.5.1"
  }
}
```

and this is my package-lock.json

```
{
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 1,
  "requires": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@discordjs/collection": {
      "version": "0.1.6",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/collection/-/collection-0.1.6.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-utRNxnd9kSS2qhyivo9lMlt5qgAUasH2gb7BEOn6p0efFh24gjGomHzWKMAPn2hEReOPQZCJaRKoURwRotKucQ=="
    },
    "@discordjs/form-data": {
      "version": "3.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@discordjs/form-data/-/form-data-3.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ZfFsbgEXW71Rw/6EtBdrP5VxBJy4dthyC0tpQKGKmYFImlmmrykO14Za+BiIVduwjte0jXEBlhSKf0MWbFp9Eg==",
      "requires": {
        "asynckit": "^0.4.0",
        "combined-stream": "^1.0.8",
        "mime-types": "^2.1.12"
      }
    },
    "abort-controller": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/abort-controller/-/abort-controller-3.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-h8lQ8tacZYnR3vNQTgibj+tODHI5/+l06Au2Pcriv/Gmet0eaj4TwWH41sO9wnHDiQsEj19q0drzdWdeAHtweg==",
      "requires": {
        "event-target-shim": "^5.0.0"
      }
    },
    "asynckit": {
      "version": "0.4.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/asynckit/-/asynckit-0.4.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-x57Zf380y48robyXkLzDZkdLS3k="
    },
    "combined-stream": {
      "version": "1.0.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream/-/combined-stream-1.0.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FQN4MRfuJeHf7cBbBMJFXhKSDq+2kAArBlmRBvcvFE5BB1HZKXtSFASDhdlz9zOYwxh8lDdnvmMOe/+5cdoEdg==",
      "requires": {
        "delayed-stream": "~1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "delayed-stream": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-1.0.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-3zrhmayt+31ECqrgsp4icrJOxhk="
    },
    "discord.js": {
      "version": "12.5.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/-/discord.js-12.5.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-VwZkVaUAIOB9mKdca0I5MefPMTQJTNg0qdgi1huF3iwsFwJ0L5s/Y69AQe+iPmjuV6j9rtKoG0Ta0n9vgEIL6w==",
      "requires": {
        "@discordjs/collection": "^0.1.6",
        "@discordjs/form-data": "^3.0.1",
        "abort-controller": "^3.0.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
        "prism-media": "^1.2.2",
        "setimmediate": "^1.0.5",
        "tweetnacl": "^1.0.3",
        "ws": "^7.3.1"
      }
    },
    "event-target-shim": {
      "version": "5.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/event-target-shim/-/event-target-shim-5.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-i/2XbnSz/uxRCU6+NdVJgKWDTM427+MqYbkQzD321DuCQJUqOuJKIA0IM2+W2xtYHdKOmZ4dR6fExsd4SXL+WQ=="
    },
    "mime-db": {
      "version": "1.45.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-db/-/mime-db-1.45.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-CkqLUxUk15hofLoLyljJSrukZi8mAtgd+yE5uO4tqRZsdsAJKv0O+rFMhVDRJgozy+yG6md5KwuXhD4ocIoP+w=="
    },
    "mime-types": {
      "version": "2.1.28",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.28.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-0TO2yJ5YHYr7M2zzT7gDU1tbwHxEUWBCLt0lscSNpcdAfFyJOVEpRYNS7EXVcTLNj/25QO8gulHC5JtTzSE2UQ==",
      "requires": {
        "mime-db": "1.45.0"
      }
    },
    "node-fetch": {
      "version": "2.6.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-fetch/-/node-fetch-2.6.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-V4aYg89jEoVRxRb2fJdAg8FHvI7cEyYdVAh94HH0UIK8oJxUfkjlDQN9RbMx+bEjP7+ggMiFRprSti032Oipxw=="
    },
    "prism-media": {
      "version": "1.2.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/prism-media/-/prism-media-1.2.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-fSrR66n0l6roW9Rx4rSLMyTPTjRTiXy5RVqDOurACQ6si1rKHHKDU5gwBJoCsIV0R3o9gi+K50akl/qyw1C74A=="
    },
    "setimmediate": {
      "version": "1.0.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/setimmediate/-/setimmediate-1.0.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-KQy7Iy4waULX1+qbg3Mqt4VvgoU="
    },
    "tweetnacl": {
      "version": "1.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/tweetnacl/-/tweetnacl-1.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-6rt+RN7aOi1nGMyC4Xa5DdYiukl2UWCbcJft7YhxReBGQD7OAM8Pbxw6YMo4r2diNEA8FEmu32YOn9rhaiE5yw=="
    },
    "ws": {
      "version": "7.4.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-7.4.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-T4tewALS3+qsrpGI/8dqNMLIVdq/g/85U98HPMa6F0m6xTbvhXU6RCQLqPH3+SlomNV/LdY6RXEbBpMH6EOJnA=="
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's probably not a problem of npm itself but your script is returning a non-zero exit code. Maybe the reason for that is printed above that error. But maybe this is caused by copying around your files and folders in arbitrary locations. Have you tried looking into the provided logfile `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-26T07_31_43_854Z-debug.log`

Comment: I have, and since im like 5 days into coding, i cant really extract information out of it..
ill post it in my main message for you

Comment: have you installed discord.jswith npm first of all?
if not int the same directory with package.json, in cmd do `npm i discord.js`

Comment: Please include the package.json file

Comment: alright thats in my main message now

Comment: @NrdyBhu1 I think so, the guy who got me into this made me install NPM, Discordjs and some more but, my bot worked fine yesterday and then later in the evening i got this problem idk why. theres only one piece of code i wrote myself competely
the one with     if (fromID === me && text.includes("/repeat") ) {

Comment: This was probably caused by copying around your files. If I setup a new npm project in an empty directory with `npm init` and install the required packages, your code runs just fine ...

Comment: @NrdyBhu1 PS D:\scripts> npm i discord.js
npm WARN discord-bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN discord-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ discord.js@12.5.1
updated 1 package and audited 15 packages in 0.91s
found 0 vulnerabilities

PS D:\scripts>
is what it said

Comment: @derpirscher
```
PS D:\script> npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
It only covers the most common items, and tries to guess sensible defaults.

See `npm help init` for definitive documentation on these fields
and exactly what they do.

Use `npm install <pkg>` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
package name: (script)
```
i made a new folder, set the Set-Location -path to it, and then this is what it said. should  i put my botcode in a new file in there?

Comment: Try removing the node_modules folder and then reinstall the dependencies.

Comment: alright in my new folder, i got packagelock,json - package.json - nodemodules - index.js (my bot script)
and  it gives the same error now :/ 



npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: could there maybbe be an error in this piece of the `package.json` ?
 "start": "node index.js" since in the error i see this standing there

Comment: @James no this is fine. Have you deleted the node_modules folder before running `npm install` ?

Comment: @Seblor i took the ones from my old file, ill delete the oens i have now and run 
Npm install again

Comment: @Seblor i did as you said, and i got this:

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! discord-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the discord-bot@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\James Kok\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-26T09_37_22_237Z-debug.log
PS D:\script> a

Comment: If i were to reinstall vscode and delete all the files of npm and json i have atm, and reinstall it all, would that work?

Comment: @James the problem is not from VSCode. Maybe reinstall Node

Comment: how do i do t hat? @seblor\

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your looking at the wrong error.

You called a variable named `fromID` I'm guessing you mean the author id, which can be called with

```js
if (msg.author.id !== client.user.id && ..)
```